# Importing html files into literal

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack for a very simple application where I need to import a html file into a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I have my entry file called app.js where I import:

```
import {info} from "./info";
import t from "../components/test.html"
```

Content inside info.js

```
export let info = {
  user: "",
  name: "Some name"
};
```

Content inside test.html

```
<div>
  <b>Name: </b> ${info.name}
</div>
```

By `console.log(t);` I get `<div> <b>Name: </b> ${info.name} </div>`. Ok so far..

And this is what I wanted to do: `` let x = eval('`'+t+'`'); `` but get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: info is not defined`

Is there a way to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At compile time use https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates, At browser using methods for manage the DOM tree.

Comment: That worked, thanks for the help